# Best way to implement logic so two similar classes have common as well as different functionality

Tags: c#, polymorphism, data-access-layer, factory-pattern

I am trying to setup a database access layer that can talk to lets say SQL db as well as some noSQL DB. I am thinking of having one interface like IDataManager that would have common functions like GetData() putData(), addTable() , dropTable(), as well as both Dbs can have individual functionality like noSQL DB can allow inserting data from XML or flat file etc.
How do I go about implementing a factory sort of logic or an access logic for this heirarchy in my client code ?

```
interface IdataManager 
{
   getData();
   putData();
   addTable();
   dropTable();
}

class NoSQLManager : Idatamanager
{
   //implements all common functions
   getData();
   putData();
   addTable();
   dropTable();

   //also declares some additional ones 
   putDatausingXML();
}

class SQLManager : Idatamanager
{
   //implements all common functions
   getData();
   putData();
   addTable();
   dropTable();

   //also declares some additional ones 
   putDatausinglocaltable();
}

//Now in my code to access above DAL logic , lets say I create a simple factory 

class dataAccessFactory 
{
  IdataManager getDataManager(int id)
  {
    dataManager dm = null;
    if(id==1)
      dm = new NoSQLManager();
    else if(id==2)
      dm = new SQLManager();
    return dm;
  }
}

Logic to access above factory :

dataAccessFactory daf = new dataAccessFactory ();
IdataManager noSqlObj = daf.getDataManager(1);
noSqlObj.putDatausingXML(); //problem this wont work.
```

I want to be able to access extra functions like putDatausingXML as well as common functions like getData() using noSqlObj

But using given inheritance and logic, I will only be able to access functions that part of base interface IdataManager .

Answer (score 0):

The point of interfaces is so that the next layer up can write code using the interface's methods and not worry about the underlying implementation.  What you're trying to do nullifies the point of using interfaces in the first place.  If you need to call something like `putDataUsingXML()` then the caller is aware that they need a NOSQL style db, not a SQL db.  Even your variable name is `noSqlObj`.  So what's the point of creating an interface that purports to hide those details?

If you really need to do this, you could cast the interface to the underlying implementation.

```
((NoSqlManager)noSqlObj).putDatausingXML();
```

But you should really re-evaluate what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thats correct, agreed. But is there a way something like Factory Method pattern , where you can have business logic common to both implementations - NoSqlManager & SQLManager  of the interface IdataManager as well as specific to them .
For business logic you can create specific factories and include business logic within them. But how to do something similar for functions that can be different for both implementations - if there is a similar way to abstract this from the client.

Comment: Also, if I create two separate interfaces , one for common functionality and another for specific functionality, and let NoSqlManager class implement both -- Is there a way to access both set of functionalities in abstracted way other than creating instance of NoSqlManager

Comment: Yes, you can have a single instance of NoSqlManager (obtained from a factory if you like) and keep casting it to multiple different interfaces that it implements.  That will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try it out and see if that works for my case :)